# How can I remove the oldest element from stack?

Tags: c++, stack

How can I remove the oldest element from stack instead of throwing fullStackException?
Isn't there any algorithm about it?

Comment: what language / framework ?

Comment: Sorry for forgetting it's C/C++

Comment: There is no `fullStackException` for `std::stack`, the underlying container (`std::deque`) is dynamic.

Comment: I think you may be using the wrong data structure. If you want FIFO behaviour try a queue.

Comment: You're clearly using some non-standard library.  Without seeing its code or at least its API, we can't help you.

Comment: If you could do this it wouldn't be a stack.

Comment: If you can remove the oldest element, it isn't a stack.  Formally, if you can access any element but the youngest, it isn't a stack.  (The `std::stack` only allows access to top of stack.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aren't you confusing yourself with queue? A stack allowing removal of oldest element can be called as dequeue. In any case there are multiple dimensions to this question

I won't say removal of oldest element is possible in (a single)stack. However you can always peek the oldest element. By keeping a variable. define that variable when first element is inserted. And when ever you have to peek. Just use that variable.

And if you really want to remove the oldest element and you are only allowed to use stack only. Then probably you can do this using two stacks

stack1 contains all the elements. Stack2 is empty.

**Pseudocode**

```
while(!stack1.empty()){
    stack2.push(stack1.pop());
}
stack2.pop();
while(!stack2.empty()){
    stack1.push();    //Or Instead of 2nd while you can also swap the stack1 and stack2(like swapping two variables)
}
```

The above code is actually more popularly known by the name **implementing queue using 2 stacks**. You may want to look upon it

Answer (score 2):

A typical stack is a data structure that allows to push new entries and to view and pop the latest pushed entry (the top).

If you have an implementation that allows you to access the bottom entry, then strictly speaking, it is not a stack.

However, if you make it yourself, it is possible to make a LIFO datastructure where the oldest entry can be removed.  Just make sure to use a double linked list and keep a pointer to the bottom entry.  Notice that this is close to `std::deque`.

Answer (score 1):

If you can access or remove the oldest element, it isn't
a stack.  Still, if you want a stack with a maximum size, which
removes the oldest element to make room when it grows too big,
you can do this by deriving from `std::stack`.  The standard
makes the underling container a protected data member, so the
derived class *can* access it.